# SQL error 1064 in a hasMany through relationship

Tags: cakephp

I've been trying to solve this for the past 3 days and nothing has came up. I've researched a lot and this errors usually come up when CakePHP can't find my model or I have some name wrong in my relationships. Well I tried looking at everything, but still couldn't find where the error is.
I have a User model, a Project model and a UserRole model which is the join table used by the hasMany through relationship.

File names:

> user.php project.php user_role.php

Models:

```
class UserRole extends AppModel {
...
var $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Project' => array(
        'className' => 'Project',
        'foreignKey' => 'project_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
class User extends AppModel {
...
var $hasMany = array(
...
    'UserRole' => array(
        'className' => 'UserRole',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),

);
class Project extends AppModel {
...
var $hasMany = array(
...
    'UserRole' => array(
        'className' => 'UserRole',
        'foreignKey' => 'project_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
);
```

When I try calling any method from UserRole from User, it give me the 1064 SQL error. Any hint on where could be the problem?

Things I've tried so far: checked if UserRole is being loaded, and it is. And I can call the UserRole functions from an element, they are working fine.

FUNCTIONS (get_related_clients is in Users and the other is in UserRole):

```
function get_related_clients ($id_user, $relationship_type) {
$id_names = $this->User->UserRole->get_id_users($id_user,$relationship_type);
    ...
}
function get_id_users ($id_agency = null,$type = null) {
    $params_1 = array(
        'conditions' => array('UserRole.user_id' => $id_agency)
    );
    $user_projects = $this->UserRole->find('all',$params_1);
    $projects = array();
    for ($i = 0; !empty($user_projects[$i]); $i++) {
        $projects[] = $user_projects[$i]['UserRole']['project_id'];
    }
    $clients = array();
    foreach ($projects as $project) { //pega o id de todos os usuarios que sao clientes da lista de projetos anteriores
        $params_2 = array(
            'conditions' => array('UserRole.project_id' => $project, 'UserRole.role' => $type) 
        );
        $client_project = $this->UserRole->find('first',$params_2);
        if ($id_agency != $client_project['UserRole']['user_id']) { $clients[] = $client_project['UserRole']['user_id']; } // voce nao pode ser cliente de voce mesmo
    }
    return $clients;
}
```

ERROR:

```
 Warning (512): SQL Error: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'get_id_users' at line 1
DboSource::showQuery() - CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 684
DboSource::execute() - CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 266
DboSource::fetchAll() - CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 410
DboSource::query() - CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 364
Model::call__() - CORE/cake/libs/model/model.php, line 502
Overloadable::__call() - CORE/cake/libs/overloadable_php5.php, line 50
UserRole::get_id_users() - [internal], line ??
UsersController::get_related_clients() - APP/controllers/users_controller.php, line 71
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/cake/dispatcher.php, line 204
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/cake/dispatcher.php, line 171
Object::requestAction() - CORE/cake/libs/object.php, line 95
include - APP/views/elements/client_list.ctp, line 2
View::_render() - CORE/cake/libs/view/view.php, line 731
View::element() - CORE/cake/libs/view/view.php, line 392
include - APP/views/projects/index.ctp, line 45
View::_render() - CORE/cake/libs/view/view.php, line 731
```

**UPDATE:**
If I call the function through requestAction it works. :(

Comment: Post your controller code (where you're querying model). And description of error, with query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was: I can't call functions from another controller, unless it's declared with the model. :)

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to call `get_id_users` function on `UserRole` model, while it appears to be in  `UserRoles` controller. Hence the error.

**Update**:

This line:

```
UserRole::get_id_users() - [internal], line ??
```

in your log clearly shows that PHP did not find function `get_id_users()` in `UserRole` class (which should be model judging by its name, but since you've mistaken the names from the very start its hard to tell without actually looking at your files).

**Conclusion**: rebake your app (at least `User` and `UserRole` models and controllers), doing naming right this time.

Comment: I think the calling is right. If I change $this->User->UserRole->get_id_users($id_user,$relationship_type); to $this->User->UserRoles->get_id_users($id_user,$relationship_type); it gives me "Fatal error: Call to a member function get_id_users() on a non-object". :(

Comment: Where is your `get_id_users()` function defined? It should be in `UserRole` model, not in `UserRoles` controller.

Comment: It is defined in UserRole. I mistyped the name UserRole and added an 's' at the end of it. Them model/controller/view were created by Bake.

Comment: If you model is called `UserRoles`, why you're calling `$this->User->UserRole`? See my update in the answer. **Conclusion**: Cake heavily relies on naming conventions, and errors like 'adding s by mistake' can really make things FUBAR. I recommend you just rebake your app, and then try again, or we'll be going in circles forever.

Comment: I add an 's' by mistake on my answer, not on my app. Anyway I rebaked User and UserRole and I still got nothing. I'll try to build another app from 0 and see if I can make it work.

Comment: Are you sure `get_id_users()` is defined in **model, not in controller**?

Comment: @dccarmo let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1554/discussion-between-lxa-and-dccarmo)